# Role of Hg2+ as catalyst

Tags: organic-chemistry, catalysis

in the reaction of addition of hydrogen halides to alkynes $\ce{Hg^2+}$ can be used as a catalyst. But what is its role? How does it increase the rate of reaction.

I think that the vacant orbitals in Hg would help in the process of ionisation of hydrogen halides. Is this concept correct? please help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main use of $\ce{Hg}$$^{\text{2+}}$ is to ***polarize*** the electron cloud of the alkyne.
Else the attacking specie wont be able to approach the bond

Comment: You know you can comment under questions? If you wanna say one sentence from the top of your head, comment is a way to go.

Comment: Im sorry, but i aint got a commentable amount of reputation, like you. Seemingly want to maximize earnings dude @Mithoron

Comment: @QuarkyLittleThing you mean that cyclic intermediate that $\ce{Hg^2+}$ forms with triple bond

Comment: Then make better answers. Also it's not like rep is a big deal.